# getting a black screen instead of the background image

Tags: andengine

Was creating a my first game in AndEngine and am only getting a black screen instead of getting the background image and play button..
Here the code
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

private BoundCamera camera;
private float WIDTH = 800;
private float HEIGHT = 480;

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions engineOptions){
    return new LimitedFPSEngine(engineOptions,60);
}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    camera = new BoundCamera(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new
            EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(),camera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws IOException {

}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws IOException {

}
}
```

BaseScene.java

```
public abstract class BaseScene extends Scene {

protected Engine engine;
protected Activity activity;
protected ResourceManager resourceManager;
protected VertexBufferObjectManager vbom;
protected Camera camera;

public BaseScene(){
    this.resourceManager = ResourceManager.getInstance();

    this.activity = resourceManager.activity;
    this.engine = resourceManager.engine;
    this.vbom = resourceManager.vbom;
    this.camera = resourceManager.camera;

    createScene();
}

public abstract void createScene();
public abstract void onBackKeyPressed();
public abstract SceneManager.SceneType getSceneType();
public abstract void disposeScene();
}
```

SceneManager.java

```
public class SceneManager {

private BaseScene mainMenu;
private BaseScene gameScene;

private BaseScene currentScene;

private static final SceneManager INSTANCE = new SceneManager();

private SceneType currentSceneType = SceneType.SCENE_MENU;

private Engine engine = ResourceManager.getInstance().engine;

public enum SceneType
{
    SCENE_MENU,
    SCENE_GAME
}

public void setScene(BaseScene scene){

    engine.setScene(scene);

    currentScene = scene;

    currentSceneType = scene.getSceneType();

}

public static SceneManager getInstance(){
    return INSTANCE;
}

public SceneType getSceneType(){
    return currentSceneType;
}
}
```

I have 2 more classes MainMenu and ResourceManager
What is the problem here?

Comment: Where are your drawing methods? If you draw nothing, it's very normal that the scene is emtpy (black)